# Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher; (3)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I've installed Eclipse, JDK8, Android SDK and libGDX. When I generated project from gdx_setup.jar I got my projeсts for desktop and Android and when I'm trying to start AndroidLauncher I have crash.

---

Here is the code of AndroidLauncher:

```
package com.game.test;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.game.test.MainClassOfTestGame;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MainClassOfTestGame(), config);
    }
}
```

---

and here is LogCat:

```
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher; (3)
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): Link of class 'Lcom/game/test/AndroidLauncher;' failed
03-12 05:08:46.056: D/AndroidRuntime(2413): Shutting down VM
03-12 05:08:46.056: W/dalvikvm(2413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d7cb20)
03-12 05:08:46.064: E/AndroidRuntime(2413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

---

[Android Private Libraries added to the build path.  it didn't solve my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iebhE.png)

---

Pls, if u know something about my problem, help me.

P.S. sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. it was necessary to put a check mark also on the Project and External Dependencies. Although I've done it before, but it hasn't worked until now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -> Right Click on your Project then

**Goto Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export**

when you are there you should check the Android Private Libraries and then click OK.

if you still have this problem delete all files inside your bin folder and rebuilt you project.

Hope this to help you!

Comment: it didn't solve my problem. i read it on many forums and tryed it before ask the questions. look screenshot in my question.

Comment: Moreover, Android Private Libraries has already been selected, before i checked it